# Flutter Focus onKeyEvent triggers for both key down and up

Tags: flutter, dart, focus, keyevent

The `Focus` widget in Flutter can detect and handle `KeyEvent`s. However, it will trigger on both key down and up events (so it calls its assigned callback twice for each press). Given a `KeyEvent`, how can I detect if it was a key down or up event so I can make the callback only react to one of those two events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This really needs to be in the docs.

The `KeyEvent` passed is really one of the few subclasses that include `KeyDownEvent` and `KeyUpEvent` so you can check the type with

```dart
if(event is KeyDownEvent) {
  // ...
}
```